# Magento 1.9 Installation Error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to install magento 1.9 on my web hosting server .

I ftp-ed the files into my hosted website but experience the following error when i try to access my URL.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http' not found in /home/bf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 1238
```

I tried a google search but i am unable to find anything relevant .

Answer (score 1):

Just download the Fresh copy from Magento community again. Also make sure that your server has all the prerequisite for Magento as mentioned in below link.
 http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that below files exist in this directory

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure you have enabled curl on your server and with have right file permission.
2.Make sure file should exist on following path:
/home/bf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php

3.Make sure compilation mode is disabled. 
/home/bf/public_html/includes/config.php
Every thing inside should be commented.

4.If it does not work, you have to debug this.

Open index.php in root and add these line of code,

```
      Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It will show you why error is coming.Once you will find the root cause, you can get the solution on google or any forum.